# Aqueduct heroku deployment problems

Tags: heroku, dart, aqueduct

I am trying to follow [the official tutorial](https://aqueduct.io/docs/deploy/deploy_heroku/) on how to deploy apps on Heroku
I am however getting the following error:

```
remote: Precompiled aqueduct:aqueduct.
remote: Precompiled test:test.
remote: *** Running pub build
remote: Building with "pub build"
remote: Dart 2 has a new build system. Learn how to migrate from pub build and
remote: pub serve: https://webdev.dartlang.org/dart-2
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Dart app.
```

I can't seem to find any hints on what I can change to fix the error (It shouldn't really be using pub build or serve. unless aqueduct calls it under the hood)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a web folder in the root of your project causes the buildpack to try and run 'pub build'